# Dutch citizenship through marriage

Tags: netherlands, citizenship, marriage

I have been married to a Dutch citizen for 20 years. We live and work in South Africa. Can I apply for Dutch citizenship through marriage?

Comment: Have you done any research yourself? Do you speak Dutch? What is your current citizenship?

Comment: https://ind.nl/en/dutch-citizenship/Pages/Naturalisation.aspx